# Как на изображение найти круг и получить его координаты?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как получить расположение круга на изображении? Сделал небольшой код который преобразовывает изображение из RBG в черно-белое.
Изображение до:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После преображение в черно белое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно найти круг на этом изображении

На изображении в черно-белом думаю будет куда легче найти круг, думаю лучше работать с ним, **хотелось бы послушать как можно найти круг на изображении и его координаты**

Comment: вот эта штука вам не подойдёт ? https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles

Comment: [![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV4g6.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV4g6.jpg) Для этого изображения этот код не работает. Находит 8 кругов, и все мимо. [![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIvmJ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIvmJ.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

При помощи [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles) смог найти найти там круг. Даже в цветной картинке.

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("image", metavar="image_file", help = "Image file")
args = parser.parse_args()

image = cv2.imread(args.image)
image_output = image.copy()
# конвертация в grayscale
image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# детекция кругов
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image_gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.5, 20, param1=1, param2=20, minRadius=8, maxRadius=12)

if circles is not None:
    # конвертация координат центра и радиуса в int
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")

    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        print(f"Center: {x},{y}   Radius: {r}")
        # обведём найденный круг
        cv2.circle(image_output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 1)
        # и ткнём точку в центр
        cv2.circle(image_output, (x, y), 2, (255, 0 , 255), -1)

    cv2.imshow("The result", image_output)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Результат]

---

Второй вариант, который основан на поиске шаблона. Будет работать, если размер круга всегда одинаков.

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

def detect_circle(image_file_name):
    print(image_file_name)
    # создаём шаблон нашего круга, который будем искать
    r = 10 # радиус
    image_template = np.zeros((r*2+1, r*2+1), np.uint8)
    cv2.circle(image_template, (r, r), r, 255, -1)

    # входная картинка
    image = cv2.imread(image_file_name)
    # добавим немного пикселей с каждой стороны 
    # чтобы компенсировать возможно обрезанный круг
    image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, *[r//2]*4, cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
    image_output = image.copy()

    # конвертация в grayscale
    image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # найдём максимальную яркость 
    # будем использовать её как границу между чёрным и белым
    pixels = dict(zip(*np.unique(image_gray, return_counts=True)))
    max_pixel = sorted(pixels.keys())[-1]
    # конвертация в чёрно-белое
    image_bw = cv2.threshold(image_gray, max_pixel-1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    # подсчитаем количество чёрных и белых пикселей
    pixels = dict(zip(*np.unique(image_bw, return_counts=True)))
    if pixels[0] < pixels[255]:
        # похоже, что мы имеем тёмные элементы на светлом фоне
        # так что делаем из нашего шаблона круга негатив
        image_template = cv2.bitwise_not(image_template)

    x,y = cv2.minMaxLoc(cv2.matchTemplate(image_bw, image_template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED))[-1]

    # всякая демонстрационная фигня
    print(f"Center: {x},{y}   Radius: {r}")

    # обведём найденный круг
    cv2.circle(image_output, (x+r, y+r), r, (0, 255, 0), 1)
    # и ткнём точку в центр
    cv2.circle(image_output, (x+r, y+r), 2, (255, 0 , 255), -1)

    cv2.imshow("The result", np.hstack([image, cv2.cvtColor(image_gray, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR), cv2.cvtColor(image_bw, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR), image_output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    # конец всякой демонстрационной фигни
    
    return x,y
    
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("images", metavar="image_file", nargs='+', help = "Image file")
args = parser.parse_args()

for file_name in args.images:
    print(detect_circle(file_name))
```

[image: Скрин]

Comment: А возможно как то получать не серый круг, а допустим черный или белый в преобразованном? Т.к. это изображении часто меняет свой задний фон, и цвета кругов, там может быть любой цвет и его никак не предугадать

Comment: А этой программе всё-равно. Она не завязана на цветах.

Comment: Попробуйте Сделать под такие избражения, пытался подобрать настройки, много времени потерял в пустую, [https://imgur.com/a/AVST1Vc](https://imgur.com/a/AVST1Vc) - вот изображения такого же типа в которых нужно найти круги, во многих он просто не может его найти
Он находит либо ошибочный круг, либо и вовсе его не находит.

Comment: @script1ck Я добавил другой вариант, которой определяет круг по шаблону. На всех ваших картинках определил верно.